# Python's is losing scope when I use a classmethod as a decorator wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I:

1. Use a classmethod as a decorator wrapper
2. Have a conditional statement inside the decorator
3. Put a variable assignment inside the decorator

python raises an UnboundLocalError exception.

However, when I remove the variable assignment and replace it with a print function everything works fine (it does print). Which indicate that the variable is indeed defined.

Snippet 1

```
class TestClass:
    @classmethod
    def include(cls, name=None):
        def dec(func):
            if name is None:
                name=1
            return func
        return dec
@TestClass.include()
def test(): pass
```

Snippet 2

```
class TestClass:
    @classmethod
    def include(cls, name=None):
        def dec(func):
            if name is None:
                print(name)
            return func
        return dec
@TestClass.include()
def test(): pass
```

In snippet 1 nothing should happen but it raised the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    @TestClass.include()
  File "main.py", line 5, in dec
    if name is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Snippet 2 prints None as it should.

Am I doing something wrong? or is this a problem in python's implementation?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve by assigning to `name`, though.

Comment: This is a simplified version but in the real one I am sitting name to the function name. But this is irrelevant since the same error happens even when I set it to an integer. What am I doing that is wrong?

Comment: You're either: 1. Trying to access a local variable before you've actually assigned to it (Python's guess, hence the error message); or 2. Trying to assign to a non-local variable without being explicit about that. If you read any of the many other questions about UnboundLocalError, this should become clear. But it's still not clear what the point is, maybe a less abstract example would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator is a red herring. All that is happening here is that you are trying to assign to the nonlocal variable `name` from inside the function `dec`.

Whenever you assign to a variable inside a function in Python that variable is automatically local to the function unless you explicitly tell Python that it should be treated as `nonlocal` or `global`.

Just add a `nonlocal` declaration and it will do what you expected:

```
class TestClass:
    @classmethod
    def include(cls, name=None):
        def dec(func):
            nonlocal name 
            if name is None:
                name=1
            return func
        return dec
@TestClass.include()
def test(): pass
```

Comment: Makes sense, but why is the exception referring to the if statement and not the variable assignment? The if statement seem to work fine in the second case.

Comment: @user3546184 because there's nothing wrong with assigning to a local variable. There is something wrong with accessing a local variable before it has been assigned and it's the `if` that tries to access the unset local. In the second case the variable is never assigned so it is automatically `nonlocal`, you don't have to tell Python in that case.